# Как сделать массив с рандомными данными?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать массив с рандомными данными, но самое главное чтобы выглядело естественно, реский рост или падение, или резкое или медленное падение.

В массиве используются цифры как цены для графика

```js
let array = [12.1, 12.3, 12.4, 14.7, 18.2, 18.3, 18.4, 8.7, 5.3, 5.1, 12.1, 12.2, 12.3, 25.5, 25.4, 25.1];
console.log(array);
```

В `js` есть `Math.random()` но как его применить для такого не понятно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arr = [];
let arrLength = 25;
    
for (let i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
  let numb = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000) / 10
  arr.push(numb)
}
    
console.log(arr)
```

в цикле уже можно подбирать ближайшие значения (плюс или минус 5, например) и их тоже пушить в arr

Comment: Спасибо, почти нормальный генерируется массив, на основе него еще попробую доработать